# Cloudfare session drops

Tags: cloudflare

so ive got a custom php script upand running

I followed the cloudfare guide to change NS records to their own and now my login system is experiencing session drops. Members are logged out in a minute or so. I know approximatelly what that is related but didnt find any sufficient answers online or on their discord or community.

This is what ive found so far

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/problem-with-user-session-drop/69671/2
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/session-drop-kick-out-logout-problem/126208/5

and this link which is broken
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200805497-Restoring-Visitor-IPs

Comment: being a custom script its hard to tell, please include more details about your setup, like is it load balanced? how do you store sessions? file or db? is it after exactly 60seconds or less or more? what actions does the user do to cause logout?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It is not load balanced , the session is stored in a cookie. I am using the simple $_COOKIE["id" to identify and have a database connected with all the stuff. The users just log out in some seconds, max in a minute. i think it has to do with the fact that traffic passing through cloudfare sends back a different IP and cant identify  the user. But i dont understand what the solution could be.